# Android: InputStreamReader .readLine method reading all lines instead of just one

Tags: java, android, inputstreamreader

I'm trying to read a txt file line by line, but it's sucking up the whole file into the first line. Is it my code, or perhaps the cr/lf encoding of the file itself?

```
 try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("file")));
            String inputString;
            try {
                while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) { 
...
```

Comment: It means your file has only one line.

Comment: Please show sample input and output that demonstrates exactly what you're seeing that is unexpected.

Comment: You're calling it in a loop. That loop will only exit when you've read the entire file. However it doesn't 'suck up the whole file into the first line', unless there is only one line. Maybe your code does that, but as you haven't posted it, only you can know. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: My text file has 8 lines, each separated by a carriage return--at least that's how it appears in Windows. But during debugging, Android displays all 8 lines, back-to-back, for "inputString" the first iteration of the loop. By some answers here, it sounds like my code should be correct, so I'm guessing Android doesn't recognize the cr/lf for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Make up your mind. First you say the lines are separated by a carriage return. Then you say it's CR/LF. Which is it? Is it really either of them?

Comment: What I mean is, my text file has visual breaks between lines--created by hitting the Enter key--but I have no idea what invisible character Notepad or Android are "seeing" (or more to the point, NOT seeing). This file works fine in Perl and Visual Basic, but I'm new to Java and don't know why Android doesn't accept the line breaks.

Comment: Well you're going to have to find out. Read the file char by char and print the hex values.

Comment: I figured it out. Android doesn't include the newline character (\n) as part of a line when it writes a line from one file to another. My app does this in another part of the program, so it was effectively stripping out the newline. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: What `readLine()` recognises as an end of line is specified in the Javadoc; not platform-dependent; and includes `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n`. And it *removes* whatever the line terminator was. Which explains the problem.